# Firefox 13 plugin for proxying only specific domains

Tags: firefox, proxy, browser-addons

I'm having issues with specific domains on my ISP (for example cdn.arstechnica.com, and vexxarr.com), and am currently accessing these sites over the tor browser bundle. I'd like to be able to create a list of sites to proxy, and proxy these *and only these* through a proxy server I control (or tor) so that things actually *work* properly with these sites, pending my ISP fixing them. [proxmate](http://www.personalitycores.com/projects/proxmate/) might do this eventually, but are there any other extensions that would let me proxy specific sites only?

I'm currently running firefox 13 on windows 7. I'll be trying to follow up on whether this is a DNS or ISP issue seperately, I just would like some way to proxy only these domains.

I wouldn't be averse to running additional software if necessary, but ideally would like to keep it to simple browser extensions.

Comment: On-topic version of this question: https://superuser.com/q/916281/176568

Answer (score 6):

You might want to try FoxyProxy - http://getfoxyproxy.org/

It lets you set a list of domains that you'd like to proxy - you can set patterns or specify domains (pattern can include wildcards or regular expressions). A brief explanation of how it can be configured [can be found here](http://getfoxyproxy.org/configuring.html).

Comment: FoxyProxy works with the new Firefox Quantum.

Comment: FoxyProxy Standard is very nice idea. If you don't want to use their VPN or Proxy services you don't have to which the site may not make clear.