# How to force browsers to use proxy server for specific domains such as google.com or facebook.com

Tags: proxy

I know IE allows you to force all connections through a proxy server, except specific domains or local addresses.  But is there a way to let IE to reach Internet directly, and only force connections to specific websites through proxy?

Use case is if google.com or facebook.com are blocked and I want to force connections to these sites through a VPN connection to a proxy server hosted somewhere else, while direct access to Internet for everything else.

Comment: Is using Firefox an option for you?

Comment: @DanielB ideally I'd like to be browser agnostic.  I know there are solutions for Firefox such as one listed [here](http://superuser.com/questions/433635/firefox-plugin-for-proxying-only-specific-domains) but I haven't found one for IE.

Comment: By default Chrome uses the exact same proxy settings that IE uses.  So the same steps you would use to configure IE to ignore/use the proxy will work for Chrome.

Comment: I would wager you can use a configurable local proxy, something like Privoxy, set that as your browser's full-time proxy, but then have it only pass certain requests through a second, external proxy.

Comment: @Ramhound The problem is IE only permits me to specify specific sites to be not going through a proxy server, and everything else to go through a proxy server.  I only need to have 2 sites to go through the proxy server and I don't think IE supports this hence asking this question here.  If you know there is a way to configure what I need can you please let me know how?

Comment: @ArthurKay Thanks this is interesting.  However this means I'll need to setup Privoxy on each PC (I don't want to add a PC to the LAN just to run Privoxy in server mode), and then a separate proxy server somewhere on the other end of the VPN tunnel.  Is there anyway we can do this simpler?

Comment: @user4641581 Trying to figure the reason I thought you were using Chrome.

Answer (score 16):

A generic solution to this problem is to use a custom proxy auto-configuration (PAC) file. In this file you can have arbitrary logic to select the proxy - including a white list of domains.

Here is how to do it:

- Create a text file anywhere in your local file system, e.g. `C:\ProxyAutoConfiguration.js`
- Paste the following content into that file

  ```
  function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {

      // use proxy for specific domains
      if (shExpMatch(host, "*.google.com|*.facebook.com"))
          return "PROXY yourproxy:8080";

      // by default use no proxy
      return "DIRECT";
  }
  ```
- Configure the file URL of this file (e.g. `file:///C:/ProxyAutoConfiguration.js`) as proxy auto-configuration script in your system or browser. In IE, this configuration is here: *Internet Options* > *Connections* > *LAN settings* > *Use automatic configuration script*.

For more information on the proxy auto-configuration file format, see for example this web page: https://findproxyforurl.com/example-pac-file/

Comment: Windows 10 doesn't seem to work with this at all. I gave up in the end, Windows is such a pain.

Comment: @KenSharp You are rigth, Windows 10 does not read a PAC file referenced by a file protocol. (source https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4025058/windows-10-does-not-read-a-pac-file-referenced-by-a-file-protocol). 
Solution: use a http server, serving the PAC file with correct MIME type 
`MIME Type: application/x-ns-proxy-autoconfig`
as shown here https://findproxyforurl.com/deploying-pac/

Comment: Anyway to do the same thing in linux?

Comment: Does this only apply to web browsers like IE, Chrome, etc.? Or will it also affect other applications like IM, etc.?

Comment: @RumeshMadhusanka & IvanHuang
yes AFAIK when you set it in the browser it affects only that browser. But im not entirely sure the scope of using LanSettings on windows. Maybe it only affects IE (sounds likely), maybe the whole system.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution.  There is a ton of proxy tools for Windows on Codeplex!  This way I don't have to setup something like Privoxy, which appears to be a bit overkill and harder to configure.
https://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=proxy&ac=4

Answer (score -1):

You can do that using a chrome extension. Download and install Browsec and then in the settings go to smart settings and then turn on proxy for your choice websites. Here you can read in full details. [Set Proxy for a specific website domains](https://geniushat.com/internet/set-proxy-for-a-specific-website-in-chrome)

Comment: Please read [how to recommend software in answers](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers), particularly the bits in **bold**; then edit your answer to follow the guidelines there. Thanks!

Comment: One site then you have to pay a subscription. Basically spam.