# How to enable a proxy in Firefox only for some URLs and not for every page I visit?

Tags: firefox, proxy, firefox-extensions, autoproxy

I'm using latest version of firefox (38.0.5 currently) and I need to use proxy configurations only for some URLs and not for every page.

After searching, I found an Addon for Firefox named [AutoProxy](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/autoproxy/) but after I installed I can not use its preferences to add rules and the defined rules and rules groups are all not visible and this is what I see in preferences:

[image]

And when I press "Add proxy rule..." button nothing happens.

Is there any other similar addon for Firefox to define proxy rules for automatically enabling proxy for some URLs and disabling for all others?

Comment: Browser-agnostic version of this question: https://superuser.com/q/916281/176568

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had a similar requirement and found two solutions to the problem:

1. If you do not mind paying for the service use FoxyProxy Plus. The free version of FoxyProxy should also work fine for this. You can define rules (even more advanced, e.g. based on current IP address): http://getfoxyproxy.org/fpplus/
2. More generic - Generate a local Proxy Auto Configuration aka *PAC* File.

   Sources:

   - [MozillaZine: Use proxy only for some sites](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=281605)
   - [Wikpedia: Proxy auto-config](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config)

e.g. save the following as text file on your hard drive (change accordingly)

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
  host = host.toLowerCase();
  if (dnsDomainIs(host, "site-needs-proxy.example.com") ||
      dnsDomainIs(host, "other-site-same-proxy.example.com"))
    return "PROXY XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:80"; // (IP:port)
  // add more if blocks for multiple proxies...
  return "DIRECT"; // or the default proxy
}
```

and go to *Tools* -> *Options* (or CMD+; on your Mac) -> *Advanced* -> *Network* -> *Settings* and check: *Automatic proxy configuration URL* in your Firefox and point it to the file you just created (It should also work in other browsers).

Comment: The free version of FoxyProxy should work fine for this. I use it at work all the time, with the web site I'm testing routed through my proxy and everything else going direct. You can define multiple rules, by domain or IP, with wildcards, and have each rule specify a different proxy if you want to.